# Alternative default avatar generator?

Tags: plugins, design, avatar, gravatar

Most of the commenters at my WordPress blog do not have a Gravatar account. Hence the comment section is almost always filled with the same old mystery man avatars.

I am looking for custom gravatar generators for commenters without their own avatar. So far I have only found Identicons, MonsterID’s, and Wavatars.  I find some of the avatars generated by these engines to be these ugly, scary and OTT. Also these do not blend with the blog theme and stick out like a sore thumb.

Can some one point me to a avatar generator that can generate nice looking avatars?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you call "nice" of course - it's hard to create something meaningful with an algorithm.

Someone once created [a unicorn-generator](https://unicornify.appspot.com/), which was [used on April 1, 2010 all over Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns). Your unicorn looks like this:

[image: Unicornified avatar for Ashwin]

Comment: :) Didn't login onto SO on April 1st, I totally missed it :( BTW thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 1):

The only other one supported by Gravatar is the retro generator. This is built into newer versions of WP, just select it in Settings->Discussion.

Comment: Retro is not nice too :(

Answer (score 1):

Drop this code in your function.php

```
    add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'wpb_new_gravatar' );
function wpb_new_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/custom-gravatar.png';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

Replace url with your custom avatar url. Then go into Settings > Discussion and here you can select your custom avatar. For more detail (screenshots & video) take a look on this [link](https://richcandies.com/support/how-to-change-default-gravatar-in-wordpress-without-plugin/)